# design of a mobile application to track another device location in Android Studio Code

Tags: android

Hello the stackoverflow community,
my firs name is Collince. I am currently working on my senior design project wchih consist of designing a mobile application in android studio code that would track in real time the location of a another person using the same app. I do not know where to start. it is my first time developing a mobile app. I just installed and learned the basic of android studio code.

for this project, any links or articles to help start my project would be a lot for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Maybe you should ask your tutor first?

Comment: .to be more precised with my question, if you have the app installed in your device I want the app to share the location of your device with me in real time. that way I always know where you are. I hope this brings more clarification. let me know if not

Comment: In Stack Overflow, you have to at least show some evidence of code attempts.